# Non-monotone Survival Function?

Tags: self-study, survival, density-function, exponential-distribution, hazard

I was given the task of plotting the graph of a survival function with the following details defined.

- **hazardrate** (lambda) = λ(t) = 0.2 (1 + sin(tπ/12))
- the underlying process is **exponential**

I am calculating the h(t) for each period and it basically equals to lambda based on what we have learnt in case of an exponential PDF.

It gives me a cyclic hazardrate but using the S(t) = exp(-lambda*t) leaves me a non monontone decreasing function.

I am pretty sure that I am approaching the issue from a wrong perspective and kindly asking you to help me out! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Lambda is not constant, so you have to integrate wrt t not just multiply by t

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the quick response? I am kinda new to this topic. Could you please provide some steps what should I do? Many many thanks in advance Sean!

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the [self-study] tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: done, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hazard rate

$$
\lambda(t) = 0.2(1+\sin(t\pi/12))
$$

The survival function $S(y)$ -- the proportion surviving through time $y$ -- is

$$
S(y) = \exp\bigg(-\int_0^y \lambda(t) dt\bigg) \\
$$

Computing $S(y)$ is an exercise in the basic rules of integration. Since $\lambda(t)\geq 0$, we know that $S(y)$ is monotone non-increasing in $y$.

Comment: Okay this definitely makes sense! Thank you for the response josliber!